# Git completion not working in zsh on OS X Yosemite with Homebrew

Tags: git, homebrew, zsh

I cannot get git completion to work on my freshly installed OS X Yosemite in the zsh shell. I've installed both git and zsh using homebrew:

```
brew install zsh git
```

When installing git via homebrew, it should setup tab-completion for you, but when I `git <tab>`, it just tries to tab-complete the directories, and not the git-commands. I.e. it's not giving any errors - it's just not working - like it's not set up.

### This is what I know so far

Apparently zsh will look for ways to autocomplete by looking for `_*` files in one of the directories in `$fpath`. This is mine:

```
% echo $fpath
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.0.6/share/zsh/functions
```

Looking at the first path we see:

```
% ls -l /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
lrwxr-xr-x  1 watson  admin   55 Oct 20 12:08 _git -> ../../../Cellar/git/2.1.2/share/zsh/site-functions/_git
lrwxr-xr-x  1 watson  admin   70 Oct 20 12:08 git-completion.bash -> ../../../Cellar/git/2.1.2/share/zsh/site-functions/git-completion.bash
```

So it seems to be setup to work out of the box - but it doesn't.

### This is what I've also tried

#### git-completion.bash

1. Downloading [git-completion.bash](https://github.com/git/git/raw/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash)
2. Running it using `source git-completion.bash`

This one kind of works (i.e. it enables auto-completion), but it prints a warning:

```
WARNING: this script is deprecated, please see git-completion.zsh
```

#### git-completion.zsh

So because of the above warning, I obviously also tried to download [git-completion.zsh](https://github.com/git/git/raw/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.zsh) and followed the guide in the top of the file, but it basically tells you to source the .bash file first, which is of cause still giving an error.

#### Search StackOverflow and Google

I've tried just about everything I could find by searching here and on Google, but nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: The `git-completion.zsh` script doesn't tell you to source the .bash file, the script does it by itself, it only needs to know the location. Since you have both files in the same directory that's all you need.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I just stumbled upon the answer!

In my case I was missing a few important pieces in my `.zshrc` file. But first a little background:

What I'm trying to do is setup the "[zsh Completion System](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/programming/linux/zsh-doc/zsh_23.html)". It comes with a lot of commands all named something with `comp*`. I tried to run these a few times but in many cases zsh would just tell me it didn't know them. So aparently you have to `autoload` them, among other things.

This is what I did:

I added the following lines to my `.zshrc` file:

```
autoload -U compinit && compinit
zmodload -i zsh/complist
```

Then I opened a new terminal and ran:

```
rm -f ~/.zcompdump; compinit
```

Then I opened a new terminal and now `git <tab>` worked as expected :)

If you are setting up a custom `$fpath` in your `.zshrc` file I would recommend adding these lines *after* you've modified the `$fpath` (though I don't know if it makes a difference).

Comment: Thanks.  I found that I didn't need `zmodload -i zsh/complist`, though.  FYI.

Comment: Thanks it is very helpful `autoload -U compinit && compinit` was enough for me.

Answer (score 35):

**Since macOS Catalina,...**
Apple has switched from bash to zsh as their default shell.

Now the only brew command you need to activate zsh-completions (which includes git completion) is this...

```
brew install zsh-completions
```

Then add this block to your ~/.zshrc file (which you may have to create first):

```
if type brew &>/dev/null; then
  FPATH=$(brew --prefix)/share/zsh-completions:$FPATH

  autoload -Uz compinit
  compinit
fi
```

If `compinit` reports insecure directories, you may need to fix permissions on some directories. You can use `compaudit` to find which directories need to be fixed.

See my answer on AskDifferent for more details:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/392382/77452

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked for me after I ran `chmod go-w '/usr/local/share'` and then `rm -f ~/.zcompdump; compinit` as suggested by `brew install zsh-completion`

Comment: I had to also do a:  `chmod go-w '/usr/local/share/zsh'` and `chmod go-w '/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions'`

Comment: I had to run `compaudit` and run `chmod go-w` on every dir listed in the output

Comment: Ditto; the stuff listed by the advice at the end of the `brew install` was insufficient, I had to run `compaudit` to get the list of problematic directories.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was much simpler; I forgot to change my default shell.

`echo $SHELL` and if it's `/bin/bash` then just type `chsh -s /bin/zsh`

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `.zcompdump-(...)` file I had in my home directory and plugins started working again.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS Ventura Deleting `~/.zcompdump` directory worked for me

```
$ rm -r ~/.cache/zsh
$ exec $SHELL
```

directory structure

```
$ tree ~/.cache
~/.cache
└── zsh
    ├── compcache
    │   ├── brew_all_commands
    │   ├── brew_casks
    │   └── brew_formulae
    └── compdump
```